# Tailwind CSS is overriding my responsive padding

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I'm trying to add responsive padding to a component. Since Tailwind CSS is mobile-first, I'm defining my mobile padding to `p-3` and screens at "md" and greater widths should use `p-5`. However, as you can see, the `p-3` class is overriding the `md:p-5` class. How can I fix this?

```html
<div className="flex-column flex rounded-3xl bg-slate-100 p-3 md:p-5">
```

Developer tools image:
[image]

Comment: It works as expected in [tailwind's playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/QHi0exmLE6). It seems to me that there is an issue with the way you are using tailwind. Why do you have rules coming from different files?

Comment: Nothing seems to wrong with this code. Check if you have a min-width of 768px, you might want a narrower breakpoint.

Comment: Can you include the CSS file (e.g. `app.css`) that's importing the Tailwind utility classes (`tailwindcss/base`, etc.)? Can you also add the code from the React file that's importing this CSS file?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems to be wrong with the code . It works properly which you can check below.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="flex-column flex rounded-3xl bg-slate-100 p-3 md:p-5"></div>
```

> check with multiple screen sizes.

You can check that screen size you are watching the chrome developer tools logs.

The `md` breakpoint comes into action when screen width is from `768 px to 1023px`. So check this .

If you need smaller/narrower screen width then you can use `sm` breakpoint also which comes into action when screen width is from `640 px to 767px`

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue; in my case, it was because I was using bootstrap and tailwind together.

Maybe using another CSS framework/library also causes this.